# Error compiling with minted package

Tags: lyx, miktex, windows, minted, pygments

I'm trying to use the minted package in a document. When I compile the document I get the following error:

[image]

The minted package is installed under MiKTeX, and Pygemnts is also installed
(when I `-m pip install Pygments` I get `Requirement already satisfied: Pygments in c:\users\....\python35\site-packages (2.2.0)`). I **can't** use `pygmentize` on CMD, and can't figure out what is missing (should I add something to %PATH%?).

I'm using: Windows 10, LyX 2.2, MiKTeX 2.9, and Pygments 2.2.0.
Thanks in advance.